# change the web root directory in apache (xampp)

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When I echo "PHP_SELF" in localhost running on xampp, I get the project folder as the echoed text e.g.

```
// index.php

<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>
```

The answer is

> /a3-ver-9.0/index.php

but if I was on a server with a domain, that line would just return `"/index.php"`

Is there any way I can temporarily changes the default root in xampp to reflect this?

The reason is because I use absolute paths from root to include resources e.g. images.
however these absolute paths will not work if the root is not set correctly!

Cheers

**EDIT**

To make things more clear...

I have a website with php files that return parts of the page e.g. header.php and footer.php etc.

I have an installation of wordpress and in the wordpress template, I include these files. and because im including these files from different directories, the paths inside the included files must be absolute.

however the files in the header.php are included like:

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg" />
```

now this include is correct, and when I've finished the project and upload it to my server it will correctly retrieve the image.

but when working with localhost, the root folder "/" is the folder where ALL my local projects are kept.

So i need a way to temporarily change the localhost root for each project, so i dont have to mess about changing a load of paths when the project is ready for upload!

Hope this made more sense

However when working on local host

Comment: This sounds like a terribly complicated solution to a problem that probably has a much simpler one. Can you elaborate what your issue is with including images?

Comment: I strongly advise you not to use absolute paths for resources

Comment: please read my edits. I must use absolute paths because the path to the image is different from the wordpress directory

Comment: @salman Why should i never use root paths?

Comment: Read up on relative paths

Answer (score 2):

Best way to solve this is using virtual hosts for your projects locally.
So something like www.project.local actually shows your project.

[Here](http://ailoo.net/2008/07/set-up-multiple-virtual-hosts-on-xampp-for-windows/) is a tutorial how to achieve this in xampp.

Comment: +1 This deserves the answer. It is the correct way to do what teh OP requested.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I see what you mean, here you go [this](http://www.alphapapahotel.com/change-path-to-web-root-for-xampp-on-windows/web-development/) will help you, just change the root to the folder of your current project, for example:

```
"C:/xampp/xampp/htdocs/a3-ver-9.0/"
```

Comment: That will work for one project, but will force him to pu all of his projects under that document root. Virtual hosts is a better suggestion