# iframe uses different home directory

Tags: html, iframe

directory structure:

```
htdocs
     index.php
     cms.php
     images/
          image.jpg
          otherpic.png
     content/
          home.php
          otherfile.php
```

/content/home.php contains LOADS of images. It will be included in index.php, so take note that the src only has one dot, because its read from inside index.php:

```
<img src="./images/image.jpg"></img>
```

Now cms.php holds an iframe. The iframe is supposed to be the rich text editor so that home.php can be editted.

Which brings me the following problem: When I want to load home.php inside the iframe the image sources needs to have two dots,

```
<img src="../images/image.jpg"></img>
```

because `home.php` is inside `/content/` so the iframe will see `/content/` as is its parent directory, Not `/htdocs/`.

How do I make the images show inside the iframe/text editor AND index.php?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't set the paths to start from the web root? i.e. "/images/image.jpg" (without the dots)

Comment: wow is that possible? I thought ./images/image.jpg and /images/image.jpg were the same

Comment: Yep. It is possible. To elaborate on the dots, the single dot `.` represents the current directory and the `..` represents one back from the current directory. The `/` at the very beginning goes back to the webroot.

Comment: In Firefox o Chrome you can see the source code of the page and frame.
Copy the URL of the images here.

Another thing, you do not need: </ img> simply: <img src="one_imagen.jpg"/>

Comment: I just checked it out. /images/image.jpg doesnt work while ./images/image.jpg does.. ???

Comment: In index.php: <img src="images/image.jpg"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the path to reference the web root so you don't have to adjust the tag for different directories:

`<img src="/images/image.jpg" /> (No dots at the start of path)`

To elaborate on the dots, the single dot `.` represents the current directory and the `..` represents one back from the current directory. The `/` at the very beginning goes back to the webroot.

And, by the way, the `<img>` tag doesn't have a closing `</img>` tag; you have to leave the tag without the closing tag or use the self closing `/` as I've done above.

Comment: Works. I was working inside another folder within htdocs that I forgot to add ;) THANKS dude!

Comment: That may be the case if you haven't set up the web root for that particular project. Perhaps this will help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785509/change-the-web-root-directory-in-apache-xampp